# Running Terraform in Google Cloud Build

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-build

I want to submit a build to Cloud Build to run a Terraform command to create a GKE cluster. I've followed posts like [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-use-terraform-without-server-976d922f3f72) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/managing-infrastructure-as-code). I've tried setting a backend, using `dir` and `volume` but nothing works. All builds fail like this:

```
Starting Step #1
Step #1: Already have image: hashicorp/terraform:0.14.2
Step #1: 
Step #1: Error: No configuration files
Step #1: 
Step #1: Apply requires configuration to be present. Applying without a configuration
Step #1: would mark everything for destruction, which is normally not what is desired.
Step #1: If you would like to destroy everything, run 'terraform destroy' instead.
Step #1: 
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "hashicorp/terraform:0.14.2" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

This is the backend:

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "<BUCKET_NAME>"
  }
}
```

This is the YAML:

```
steps:
- name: 'hashicorp/terraform:0.14.2'
  args: ['init']
- name: 'hashicorp/terraform:0.14.2'
  args: ['apply','-var=PROJECT_ID=$PROJECT_ID','-auto-approve']
```

What do I need to change in the YAML to allow Terraform to run successfully via Cloud Build?

Comment: Instead of running terraform, can you run `ls` to see if your files are in the right place?

Comment: I added a step to run `ls` using the `python:3.7-slim` image, it runs between the two steps in the YAML detailed above. It returns one file: `create_cluster9bzqzato`. There is no sign of any files added to the GCS bucket.

Comment: Typically the `backend` declaration is for describing where the state is stored, not the actual `*.tf` files, where are your `*.tf` files?

Comment: The *.tf files are located in the same directory from where I call the `gcloud builds submit` command? Do the *.tf files need to be saved in the GCS bucket?

Comment: No, the `*.tf` files should be within the repository that's used as the subject for your cloud build pipeline.  The end result, is if you were to do `ls` within your build pipeline, you should see all the `*.tf` files from your repo.

Comment: Ah man, can't believe I missed this requirement!

Comment: I tried adding the *.tf files to the GCS bucket without success. What did work was adding a SOURCE to my `gcloud builds submit` command as detailed here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit. Thanks @Matthew for the help, appreciate it.

Comment: @parakee can you please add your comment as an answer I will be happy to vote up